# Inner Product of Error Vector and Residual Vector

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors, inner-products, numerical-linear-algebra

I have that $A$ is a positive definite matrix and $b$ is some fixed vector. Define $r=b-Ax$ to be the residual vector and $e=A^{-1}b-x$ to be the error vector for all vectors $x$. I need to show that $\langle e,r\rangle$ is positive unless $Ax=b$. What I have done so far:

\begin{align*}
            \langle e,r\rangle&=(A^{-1}b-x)^t(b-Ax)\\
            &=(b^tA^{-1}-x^t)(b-Ax)\\
            &=b^tA^{-1}b-b^tx-x^tb+x^tAx\\
            &=b^tA^{-1}b+x^tAx-2x^tb.
        \end{align*}

I know that $b^tA^{-1}b$ and $x^tAx$ must be positive since $A$ (and $A^{-1}$ in turn) is positive definite. My issue is I don't know how to show that the $2x^tb$ term does not exceed $b^tA^{-1}b+x^tAx$. Any ideas/hints?

Comment: Note that $e=A^{-1}\,r,\:$ therefore $\:r^Te=r^TA^{-1}\,r\;$

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Rewrite $A^{-1}b-x$ as $A^{-1}(b - Ax)$. (Or alternatively, rewrite $b-Ax$ as $A (A^{-1} b - x)$.)